# RidgeClassifier giving 99% accuracy

Tags: data-science, classification, data-modeling, modeling

So this is one of my first fully indpendent data science projects on python, and I was using a dataset I gathered to predict the outcome of NBA games (if the home team won or lost). My model was giving me about 98% accuracy on my training data and a whopping 99% accuracy on my testing data and so I beleive there's definitely something wrong, I just can't figure out what

```
from sklearn.model_selection import TimeSeriesSplit
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SequentialFeatureSelector
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
```

```
time_split = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=3)
ridge_model = RidgeClassifier(alpha = 1)
feature_select = SequentialFeatureSelector(ridge_model, n_features_to_select=15,direction='forward', cv=time_split)`

remove = ['MATCHID', 'DATE', 'SEASON', 'HOME', 'AWAY', 'W_HOME']
keep = df.columns[~df.columns.isin(remove)]

scale = MinMaxScaler()
df[keep] = scale.fit_transform(df[keep])
feature_select.fit(df[keep], target)

preds = list(keep[feature_select.get_support()])
preds # 15 features we will use to predict if the home team won or lost
```

['AWAY_FG3_PCT',
'HOME_FT_PCT',
'AWAY_FT_PCT',
'HOME_OFF_REB',
'AWAY_OFF_REB',
'HOME_DEF_REB',
'HOME_AST',
'AWAY_AST',
'AWAY_STL',
'HOME_TURNOVERS',
'AWAY_TURNOVERS',
'HOME_BLK',
'HOME_PTS',
'AWAY_PTS',
'AWAY_LAST5']

```
features = df[preds]
target = df['W_HOME']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.3, shuffle=False, stratify=None)

model = ridge_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
train_score = model.score(X_train, y_train)
train_score
```

0.9894758146124266

```
predictions = model.predict(X_test)
predictions = pd.Series(predictions, index = y_test.index)

pred_table = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['PREDICTIONS', 'ACTUAL'])
pred_table['PREDICTIONS'] = predictions
pred_table['ACTUAL'] = y_test
accuracy_score(pred_table['PREDICTIONS'], pred_table['ACTUAL'])
```

0.9948064211520302

I also can link the rest of the code and the dataset if needed

so far I checked to see if the X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test were actually different and I wasn't just using a subset of the training data to test and it doesn't seem like I am.

Comment: Are the features`HOME_PTS`, and `AWAY_PTS` refer to points of the home team and the away team in that game?